# Is it possible to install third party packages for python bundled with lldb that comes with clion?

Tags: python, clion, lldb

I am wondering if i can install things like numpy or cv2 for the python that is bundled with lldb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use pip3 just like you would for any other Python install.  You just have to make sure to use the `pip3` that matches the python libraries in Xcode.app that lldb will also use.  To do that just invoke `/usr/bin/pip3` - that binary gets installed as part of Xcode.